# NSARRAY Coding error

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Can anyone notice an error in this coding???

```
NSString *textFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
practiceContent = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; 

myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,960);
myScrollView.pagingEnabled = FALSE;
myScrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];

UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,960,40)];
lblText.text = practiceContent;
[myScrollView addSubview:lblText];
[lblText release];
```

I'm trying to pass text from text.txt into a label on a scrollview...Its shows no errors when it compiles...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried inserting an NSLog(@"\n TEXT CONTENTS: %@", practiceContent); into your code to output the contents into the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
practiceContent = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; 
...
lblText.text = practiceContent;
```

`practiceContent` is an NSArray, but `lblText.text` requires an NSString. You should simply write

```
lblText.text = fileContents;
```

The reason the compiler doesn't complain is probably you've declared `practiceContent` as an `id`. The compiler cannot perform compile-time type check if the type is `id`.